# Voto Contra Em solução Concreta

Tags: debate

Achei varias perguntas parecidas mas nenhuma debate exatamente a causa do titulo.

É valido voto contra em uma resposta que oferece uma solução mesmo que outros usuários não achem uma boa pratica ?

Mesmo provando que uma solução é concreta e que a pratica existe.

Comment: Todo voto é válido, em princípio. Voto contra ou a favor é critério do votante. As recomendações de quando votar contra e a favor estão nos tooltips das próprias setinhas do voto. Salvo algum motivo pessoal ou perseguição, o voto é individual e provavelmente não cabe muita discussão, desde que não seja por perseguição pessoal, etc (e estes casos estao discutidos em outras postagens do meta).

Comment: Mas se a reposta oferecer algo claro? Essa é a questão e se tiver esforço de anos de pratica. Essa é minha duvida.

No meu ver  o voto contra(down vote) quando a resposta não faz parte da solução ou não é uma pratica nunca usada.

Comment: Essa é sua opinião sobre a resposta, a de quem negativou é diferente da sua. Como várias pessoas vão votar, automaticamente a coisa se equilibra. Só tome cuidado pra achar que o problema é do votante, de repente a postagem tem mesmo algum problema. Eu já tomei muitos negativos aparentemente injustos, mas prefiro sempre ver onde dá pra melhorar o post nesses casos, assim, todo mundo ganha. Mesmo se o negativo foi injusto, melhorar a postagem não faz mal. Se foi justo, me abriu oportunidade pra melhorar, de qualquer maneira.

Comment: @Bacco concordo, tanto que votei a favor da solução do colega! sei que a pratica tinha caído em desuso, e a resposta poderia ser melhorada. Sempre fiz valer pela simplicidade, de agora em diante vou melhorar as repostas.

Answer (score 9):

Tenho certeza que tem duplicatas, mas vou responder porque sempre alguém acha que achou uma situação diferente, e não é nada diferente. A resposta é até pra clarificar isso.

O voto contra ou a favor não é válido se for claramente um fraude ou dado de forma claramente tendenciosa para beneficiar ou prejudicar a pessoa. Até alguns votos que não são lá muito corretos são válidos e aceitos.

Não estou dizendo que é bacana dar votos sem que o conteúdo mereça, mas é válido.

E por que é válido?

Na verdade respondo com uma pergunta: quem define se algo está correto ou não?

Vamos votar nos votos? E depois votar nos votos dos votos? E assim por diante?

Se a solução é boa e teve um negativo ela receberá positivos. Claro que há um problema, se tiver um negativo tem gente que não vota porque acha que alguém pode ter visto um erro ali e ela não tem certeza. As pessoas vivem votando sem certa. pra positivo também, alguns votos ou a aceitação chamam mais votos positivos. É triste, mas as pessoas são assim.

É injusto? É. Qual a solução que você daria?

Isto é o mesmo caso de censurar algo (o que alias vivemos tempos de censura implícita e de falsa democracia), quem define o que deve ser censurado? Quase sempre é um pequeno grupo. Por isso hoje tenho uma visão diferente sobre o funcionamento de sites que permitem interação humana. O problema é que na avaliação do que deve ser censurado ou votado, ou outro tipo de classificação, para obter alguns resultados positivos aceita-se vários falsos positivos.

É enxugar gelo. E tentar resolver certos problemas com restrições fortes demais, na melhor das hipóteses, não funciona. Tem que resolver os problemas mais graves, colocar esforço nisso.

Mas sempre estou aberto a ouvir soluções viáveis para os vários problemas que enfrentamos. Em um outro mecanismo poderia melhorar como classificar o conteúdo. Com votos anônimos e sem descrição é isso aí.

Agora, eu não vi a questão específica. Quem disse que ela é concreta? Quem disse que a prática existindo a torna correta? Quem disse que o fato de uma pessoa gostar as outras não podem não gostar? Quem provou alguma coisa? Onde está essa prova?

O que venho falando é que funcionar e estar certo são coisas distintas.

[image: Funcionar e estar certo são coisas diferentes]

Você pode estar certo na sua afirmação que a solução é boa e correta, e que o voto é injusto, mas mesmo que você prove isto é complicado dar uma solução. Eu já vi casos da pessoa afirmar que votou sem critério e ficou complicado fazer alguma coisa.

Então considere o voto como um crítica e tente melhorar o que está lá. Inclusive porque nos comentários já admite que a solução é não tão boa assim.

Não estou dizendo que o voto negativo foi merecido, até porque nem sei onde foi dado, nem estou dizendo que voto porque a pessoa não gostou da solução seja adequado. Mas vai que a pessoa sabe mais que você e viu algo errado. Seria bom a pessoa dizer o que tem de errado, mas muitos não dizem porque alguns usuários reagem mal e não há desincentivo para isto não ocorrer.

Esta posição é minha, não estou falando por toda a comunidade, outros moderadores ou a empresa dona do site.

Comment: esse debate, ficou de forma genérica! Porem é valido, entendo que voto contra não é contra a pessoa mas sim contra resposta. No caso e gerar um debate para que usuários mais experientes " " no SOpt, não negative se a resposta faz parte da solução e ela é concreta. Entendo e li os outros post que o voto contra incentiva as pessoas não oferecerem uma resposta rápida. Mas no meu ver se a resposta faz parte da solução não da dar um voto contra só não votar a favor se existe uma melhor você não acha?

Answer (score 1):

Pessoalmente acho que vai de caso para caso mas que pode ser válido votar contra numa solução que resolve o problema. Assim como o Maniero disse, acaba sempre por estar também relacionado com os conhecimentos que a pessoa tem e/ou se foi influenciada.

Vale lembrar que pode ter uma solução horrível e que funcione, e acaba por incentivar outras pessoas com o mesmo problema a seguirem essa solução horrível.

Para exemplificar o que estou a tentar transmitir vamos assumir o seguinte objetivo em Javascript:

> Preciso de fazer um código que escreva na consola os números de 1 a 10

E agora considere a seguinte resposta:

```js
value = 2;
let timer = setInterval(function() {
  if (value >= Math.pow(3,3) - 7){
    clearInterval(timer);
  }
  
  print = Math.round(value/2).toFixed(0);
  console.log(print);
  value += Math.sqrt(16)-2;
},0);
```

E agora pergunto se iria votar a favor desta resposta ?

Eu certamente não iria, e provavelmente votaria contra indicando ao autor da resposta que é uma resposta totalmente despropositada para o objetivo. No entanto repare que cumpre o objetivo proposto.